# Prove whether $A \in B \wedge B \subseteq C \rightarrow A \in C$ true or not

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

If you have three sets A, B, and C; how can you prove that the problem below is true, or give a counterexample to show it's false?

$A \in B \wedge B \subseteq C \rightarrow A \in C$

Comment: Many would take that to simply be the definition of $\subseteq$, no?

Comment: I believe it is similar to that definition. The problem is I'm not sure how to prove it. Do I just go with the fact that the statement above is the definition of $\subseteq$ and therefore true??

Comment: How exactly have you defined $\subseteq$? If it's just definition, just say that and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

$A \in B \wedge B \subseteq C \rightarrow$ A is an element in B and every element b in B is also in C $\rightarrow A \in C$.

Not very much, I know, but it's simply the definition of containment.

EDIT: If you want the longer and "mushy" proof, here's a sketch:

Assume $A \in B \wedge B \subseteq C$. So for every element b $\in$ C, implies that b $\in$ C. According to assumption, $A$ is also an element in B, so from about we get A $\in$ C. QED

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $\subseteq$ might take a form like

$$X \subseteq Y \quad\iff\quad \forall \alpha.\ \alpha \in X \to \alpha \in Y.$$

Given that, you can rewrite your question

$$A \in B \wedge B \subseteq C \rightarrow A \in C$$

two ways:

$$\alpha \in B \land (\forall \beta.\ \beta \in B \to \beta \in C) \rightarrow \alpha \in C$$
which is true by instantiating $\beta$ with $\alpha$, or
$$\{\alpha\} \subseteq B \wedge B \subseteq C \rightarrow \{\alpha\} \subseteq C$$
which is true by transitivity of $\subseteq$ (if you have this property available).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

It is worth adding, not another answer (DanielY's will do fine), but a much more general point.

Often, at the beginning of a maths course, the course instructor (or the exercises in an elementary textbook) will throw in questions like this which are indeed trivial. They want you to spot that such questions *are* trivial, and thereby reveal that you have a clear and confident grasp of the basic definitions in the area.

It isn't exactly playing a trick on you, putting such a question into a list of more substantial ones, to see if you are awake and spot that the question is trivial: having done this sort of thing a lot myself over the years, I prefer to think of it as running a reality check, to confirm you are on top of the basics.

Moral: don't be fazed, early on in a course, by questions that look "too easy": they may indeed just be elementary reality checks!